# How to elegantly declare subset of set of variables

Tags: c++

lets say that requirement is this:
As a class user I would like to collect information about a subject and when class has enough information I would like for a class to return to me the list of collected data. Enough information is defined as - when all information from subset of all possible information is collected. That subset is not fixed and it is provided to the class.

For example this is list of all possible information:

```
{
   string name; 
   int age;
   char sex;
   string location;
}
```

and I want to give my users a possibility to tell me to listen from some data source(from which my class parses data) until I get the age and  sex.

Problem is that I dont know how to convey that without an enum. 
Basically my enum solution is listening to data source until I determine using using std::includes on 2 set of enums(collected, required) that I have collected all the data.

Is it possible to do it without enums?

Comment: I use enums for this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit me too... like mentioned in the Q :D I just wondered if there is a "better way"(tm)

Comment: That was my way of saying that I haven't found one yet.

Comment: You could do what any scripting language does under the hood: use strings instead of enums and hashmaps instead of structs. It's not as efficient of course, and not very "C++", if either matters. OTOH, it allows for information to be defined at runtime, it doesn't have to be known at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I want to decouple the implementation of a piece of logic from where it's needed - in this case the knowledge of "how much data is enough" - I think of a callback function.

Presumably the set of all possible data that your class can collect is known (`name`, `age`, `sex` & `location` in your example).  This means all *clients* of your class (can) know about it also, without increasing the amount of coupling & dependence.

My solution is to create an "evaluator" class that encapsulates this logic.  An instance of a subclass of this class is created by the client and handed to the data collector at the time of the initial request for data; this object is responsible for deciding (and telling the "collector") when enough data has been collected.

```
#include <string>

// The class that decides when enough data has been collected
// (Provided to class "collector" by its clients)
class evaluator
{
public:
  virtual ~evaluator() {};

  // Notification callbacks; Returning *this aids in chaining
  virtual evaluator& name_collected()     { return *this; }
  virtual evaluator& age_collected()      { return *this; }
  virtual evaluator& sex_collected()      { return *this; }
  virtual evaluator& location_collected() { return *this; }

  // Returns true when sufficient data has been collected
  virtual bool enough() = 0;
};

// The class that collects all the data
class collector
{
public:
  void collect_data( evaluator& e )
  {
    bool enough = false;
    while ( !enough )
    {
      // Listen to data source...

      // When data comes in...
      if ( /* data is name */ )
      {
        name = /* store data */
        enough = e.name_collected().enough();
      }
      else if ( /* data is age */ )
      {
        age = /* store data */
        enough = e.age_collected().enough();
      }
      /* etc. */
    }
  }

  // Data to collect
  std::string name;
  int age;
  char sex;
  std::string location;
};
```

In your example, you wanted a particular client to be able to specify that the combination of `age` and `sex` is sufficient.  So you subclass `evaluator` like so:

```
class age_and_sex_required : public evaluator
{
public:
  age_and_sex_required()
    : got_age( false )
    , got_sex( false )
  {
  }

  virtual age_and_sex_required& age_collected() override
  {
    got_age = true;
    return *this;
  }

  virtual age_and_sex_required& sex_collected() override
  {
    got_sex = true;
    return *this;
  }

  virtual bool enough() override
  {
    return got_age && got_sex;
  }

private:
  bool got_age;
  bool got_sex;
};
```

The client passes an instance of this class when requesting data:

```
collector c;
c.collect_data( age_and_sex_required() );
```

The `collect_data` method quits and returns when the `age_and_sex_required` instance reports that the amount of data collected is "enough", and you haven't built any logic, knowledge, enums, whatever, into the `collector` class.  Also, the logic of what constitutes "enough" is *infinitely configurable* with no further changes to the `collector` class.

----- EDIT -----

An alternate version would *not* use a class with the `..._collected()` methods but simply a single (typedef'd) function that accepts the `collector` as a parameter and returns `boolean`:

```
#include <functional>
typedef std::function< bool( collector const& ) > evaluator_t;
```

The code in `collector::collect_data(...)` would simply call

```
enough = e( *this );
```

each time a piece of data is collected.

This would eliminate the necessity of the separate `evaluator` abstract interface, but would add dependence on the `collector` class itself, as the object passed as the `evaluator_t` function would be responsible for checking the state of the `collector` object to evaluate whether enough data has been collected (and would require the `collector` to have sufficient public interface to inquire about its state):

```
bool age_and_sex_required( collector const& c )
{
  // Assuming "age" and "sex" are initialized to -1 and 'X' to indicate "empty"
  // (This could be improved by changing the members of "collector" to use
  // boost::optional<int>, boost::optional<char>, etc.)
  return (c.age >= 0) && (c.sex != 'X');
}
```

Comment: A user would have to jump through a mighty bunch of hoops just to call a library function that way. Sure it gives total control (including the possibility to write gibberish unintentionnally), but is all this really necessary?

Comment: Agreed, though it might be just one small hoop!  A simple in-line lambda works nicely: `c.collect_data( [](collector const& c){ return (c.age >= 0) && (c.sex != 'X'); } );`.  This is certainly a more complex solution than some other alternatives, but it provides great flexibility.  It's a trade-off (as always!): What's more important? Simplicity or flexibility?

Comment: This question is the OP to answer :). My vote goes to the solution that will work by default (i.e. just call the function if you don't want any of these fancy optional fields) and pass a simple parameter (the list of optional fields) if you need some fancy stuff done with them. I don't like interfaces done by C++ savvies that assume the users will be other C++ savvies. My gut feeling is, C++ is mastered by maybe 1% of the people using it, but there are a vastly greater percentage of them thinking they are part of the aforementioned 1% (or pretending to be in order not to lose their job).

Comment: For instance here, you will force the user to sprinkle his/her code with lambda functions ***and*** handle the default values that might easily be dealt with transparently by the library. A clean interface should do just the contrary IMHO, i.e. hide the dirty internals like default values and provide an easy, abstract way of specifying which data will be handled.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work for you or not, but because each item may or may not be present, `boost::optional` sprung to mind.

```
{
   boost::optional<string> name; 
   boost::optional<int> age;
   boost::optional<char> sex;
   boost::optional<string> location;
}
```

Your class could then have a `bool validate()` method which checks the presence of the required set of items. This could either be a class method, or passed in as a callback.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a value by default for each member saying "i'm required".

```
static const string required_name = /* your default name */;
// ...
```

You can also use an integer as a bitmask which will behave like a set of enums.

```
typedef int mask_type;
static const mask_type name_flag = 0x01;
static const mask_type age_flag = 0x02;
static const mask_type sex_flag = 0x04;
static const mask_type location_flag = 0x08;
//...

mask_type required = name_flag | age_flag; // need to collect name & age
collect(&my_instance, required) // collect and set required values
```

Easy to use and no overhead than a single `int` :

1. value is not required anymore : `required &= ~xx_flag`
2. no more values required : `bool(required)`
3. value is required : `bool(required & xx_flag)`
4. ...

Comment: That's exactly how I would do it. Simple, lightweight, no templating crap and it does the job. Far better than forcing the user to write a few dozen lines of code just to use a library.

Answer (score 1):

Enums seems the cleanest way to do this, but I suppose if you preferred you could use short strings with a different character corresponding to each type of data. That's not so clean but might be easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Couldnt you accomplish such behaviour by using a template and a abstract class, doing something like this?

```
class SomeAbstract
{
public:
    virtual bool getRequired()  = 0;
    virtual void setRequired(bool req) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class SomeTemplate
{
    T value;
    bool required;

public:
    TemplateName(T t)
    {
        value = t;
        required = false;
    }
    void setRequired(bool req)
    {
        required = req;
    }
    bool getRequired()
    {
        return required;
    }
    void setValue(T newValue)
    {
        value = newValue;
    }
    T getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

you can then declare your list of attributes as the same type.

```
SomeTemplate<string> name; 
SomeTemplate<int> age;
SomeTemplate<char> sex;
SomeTemplate<string> location;
```

Since the template is inheriting the same type you can store them in a  `std::vector<SomeAbstract>` and treat them all the same.

This is not tested code and the idea may have some improvements but i hope you get my point.

Comment: This boils down to adding a hidden "required" boolean to each field. You could have the same result with a default value for each field, which covers 99.99% of the real use cases (who would want to store MAX_INT in a SSE date or an empty string as a valid name?).